# Twitter Bootstrap's javascript Popover looking wrong

Tags: javascript, popover, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to implement Bootstrap JS's Popover ([this](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#popover)), and for some reason it's not showing up like it's supposed to.

This is what I'm getting

[image]

As you can see, the body of the Popover is shifted towards the left, and the border's kinda broken.

Here's my code

```
<a class="btn success" id="previewBeforeSubmit"  href="#"
 data-original-title="Test" data-content="Lorem Ipsum">Save Changes</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
   $("#previewBeforeSubmit").popover({position: 10, placement: 'above'});
</script>
```

Any clue as to what's causing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most likely a CSS conflict. Your existing css rules might be adding attributes to the ones of the popover. I would start with an inspection in FireBug and see what css rules are inherited from where.

Comment: I've experienced this problem when using their "container" example app and adding popovers.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you are using their [container example](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/container-app.html). If yes, you can fix this problem by comment out line `margin: 0 -20px`. It appears in the following block:

```
  .content {
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 0 -20px;
    ...
  }
```

Comment: Yes, that was the issue! Solved a long time ago, but still a good idea to post this for any future references.

Answer (score 2):

It's a margin thing, add

```
.popover .content {
margin: 0;
}
```

this should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The more universal fix is to add `data-container='body'` to the element to stop it from inheriting css rules from (and through) the element.